# vhs asset style parsing fluid variables only in one line

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I've following code in my fluid partial:

```xml
<v:asset.style  name="flexrows{uid}" overwrite="0" group="flex" standalone="0"  rewrite="0" namedChunks="0">
    <f:for each="{mqs}" as="mq" key="width" iteration="I">
        @media only screen and (min-width: {v:math.division(a: '{width}', fail: 1, b: '16')}em) {
            <f:if condition="{i.isFirst}">
                <f:if condition="{0:settings.row.flexdirection} == {0:'row-reverse'}">
                    .row.row{uid} > .col{
                        float:right;
                    }
                        
                    .flexbox .row.row{uid} > .col, .flexboxtweener .row.row{uid}  > .col
                    {
                        float:none;
                    }
                </f:if>
                <!-- .....some more stuff  -->
            </f:if>
        }
    </f:for>
</v:asset.style>
```

It's generating the first css block (where style "float right" its added) correct, means it is replacing `{uid}` with the actual uid. In the second css block its not replacing the `{uid}` variable. it just writes `{uid}`.

But if I split the `f:if` in two parts, for each css block one, it is doing it correct.

Is here somebody who could me explain why, or whats wrong in the above example?

Comment: it happens because of the brackets, you need to handle the variables via CDATA, so the {variables} don't get mixed with the .class{properties:values}.
I didn't tested it but `f:format.cdata` could help you.

Comment: thats kind of "working": in my generated CSS File there are now these CDATA tags. But the immediately following style block will be ignored now. The style blocks after this one then are rendered. Weird. So I keep it splitted in two f:if and work without CDATA in CSS. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you've just got to fiddle the CDATA tags, if a style block is ignored then to 99.99% the CDATA ecaping was not properly, i remember something from the dark ages in HTML4 you had to add comments to make CDATA in CSS viable.